# Random errors compiling with Mono gmcs on Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, mono, osx-snow-leopard, gmcs

I'm running OS 10.6.4,  and recently tried installing Mono. Something seems to have gone awry though, I can't even compile basic code.

The following:

```
using System;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        Console.WriteLine("Hello Mono World!")
    }   
}
```

Gives me this result:

```
user$ gmcs HelloWorld.cs 
HelloWorld.cs(8,9): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `}'
HelloWorld.cs(9,1): error CS8025: Parsing error
Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warnings
```

Lines 8 and 9 refer to the closing braces. Weird, right? Has anybody experienced this or a similar problem and would know how to fix whatever's broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the error message isn't ideal, I think the problem is you are missing a semicolon.

Comment: Wow. I'm gonna have a new personal policy: wait 3 weeks before asking on SO. Turns out that was the answer. I even realized this as your response came in. >_<